# What is the meaning of "a second time" in "I met her a second time"?

Tags: word-usage

There is a sentence like "I met her a second time. or I recorded it a second time." Does "a second time" mean "for a second time"? and if so, is it possible to drop "for" like this?  Does this mean,"It was my second time meeting her, or It was my second time recording it."?  Can I also say, "I met her the first time."?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - it is possible to drop the "for" in those sentences.

> "I met her a second time"

Is the same as saying:

> "It was my second time meeting her."

Your suggestion,

> "I met her the first time."

however, does not sound natural.

I would say either,

> "I met her **for** the first time (at a party)..."

or

> "The first time I met her (was at a party)...

Comment: Where I come from, "I met her the first time" and "The first time I met her" are both idiomatic, with nothing unnatural about them. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=met+him+the+first+time%2Cmet+her+the+first+time&year_start=1750&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmet%20him%20the%20first%20time%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmet%20her%20the%20first%20time%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @TRomano I guess what I meant is that it just doesn't sound _as good_. If you do a search on "met for the first time," the results come back with literally 100 times more prevalence than when you omit the "for."